# Controlling daily variation in A/B test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, experiment-design, ab-test

I want to run an A/B test over, hopefully, as shortest time as possible! I have **severe variations in the metric over the week** which inflates the variance of metrics and hurts the power a lot! I thought I have two options in classic statistics to remedy this, and another option that I do not know how to leverage. Would appreciate if you can clear my mind about it.

1- Statisticians use **randomized block design** to control for the variations induced by factors which is not of the main interest in experiment (day of week here). **However**, this needs giving treatment to a subset of users EVERY DAY! but we want to give treatment to some users at the beginning and track them afterwards. **Further**, this needs the test to be run over several weeks so that the daily variations can be ruled out.

2-**Paired design** is another option. Simply pair control and treatment over different days of the week. The only **downside** that I can think of is that treatment and control users who end up engaging may vary over the days of the week.

3-We have the historical pattern of metric over the past days. Is there a way to efficiently leverage that information?

Comment: Keep in mind that some of the variation cannot be controlled, for example, if you have a group of customers that visit your store only before Christmas, you need to wait till Christmas...

Comment: You might want to look up whether regression adjustment methods (aka [CUPED](https://exp-platform.com/Documents/2013-02-CUPED-ImprovingSensitivityOfControlledExperiments.pdf) depending who you talk to) may be helpful for your case.

Comment: @B.Liu Thanks man! This is absolutely awesome!